# Talend use tRest returned value in another tRest

Tags: api, etl, talend

So i have a tRest component call that uses an api to get a unique ID for a report
this first rest call is represented as follows
[image]

i need to use the unique ID returned  in another restful call to get back a  json set of data

[image]

You can see i provided a static http var called id:135329...how can i reference what was returned by the first rest call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take output from tExtractJsonFields component to tJavaRow and in that you store the returned id into globaMap.put("response_id",input_row.id);
further in your next tRest call you can get this value by calling globalMap.get("response_id")

```
tExtractJsonFields----->tJavaRow (globaMap.put("response_id",input_row.id);)
|
|
|
V
tRest (globalMap.get("response_id"));
```